# NetWorking In Safe Mode Through Command Prompt

Tags: networking, windows-vista, internet

I am wondering if there is a way to access networking from within the normal safe mode instead of the safemode with networking. I can start things like live OS's and then access the internet but starting a live OS with preloaded networking sofware on boot will crash, same for safe mode with networking and normal safe mode.

I am on windows vista.

Comment: Can you disable the Ethernet card in the BIOS to see if it is causing the crash?

Comment: This question is obsolete now, I have one I will be posting later with much more info regarding this issue, but a different problem all together, if anybody answers, I'll just give them the bounty.

Comment: If you have an active bounty and you'll be posting a question with much more info, why not edit this one?

Comment: @slhck is right - better add here : which live cd (better try more than one), the nature of the crash, the make of the network card and your computer. I understand that on the installed vista everything works correctly.

Comment: Because it's most likely by the time I get the time to put the question up, as it will be much longer than this and have much more info, the bounty on this one will have expired.

Comment: Why can't you just use safemode with networking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a simple answer to your specific question, there is no way to enable networking from safemode without networking. When you boot to that version Windows disables all networking drivers, therefore your networking devices. It does seem like if  you disable the ethernet in BIOS then it will work, but that is besides this question. The answer to this exact question is "No."